# How to use python list in "IN" operator Python Cassandra Driver?

Tags: python, cql, cassandra-2.0

i am using Python Cassandra driver and CQL on back end, i want to update the data with **IN** operator

a = [1,2,3,4]
I want to run the following query
query = session.execute("update users set status=True where userid IN(%s)",[a])

but it does not work, i want to update the record where userid in list

Can any body help me please?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
from cassandra import query

yourquery = session.execute("update users set status=True where userid IN %s", query.ValueSequence([a]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
dateList = ('2019-03-01', '2019-03-02')

cid_prep_statement = session.prepare('SELECT cid from table_name where "entry_date" **IN ?** and "language_name"=? LIMIT 10')

cassandra_cids = session.execute(cid_prep_statement, (**ValueSequence(dateList)**,'English'))
```